# Cross-referencing multiple non-consecutive figures and subfigures

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, labels, cleveref

I'm trying to create clickable figure references in the hyperref environment, and I'd want the following output format:

"... as seen in Figures 1.1a, and 1.2a-b".

For custom references I've seen the solution below:

```
\newcommand{\multiref}[2]{\autoref{#1}, \ref{#2}}
\multiref{fig:startfiglabel}{fig:endfiglabel}
```

However, my problem is that the output is '*Figure*' and not '*Figures*'. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and its `\cref` macro?

Comment: No, I'm not really familiar with the package and its macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you employ the `\cref` macro of the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package to generate the desired "look" of the cross-references.

[image]

Incidentally, in order to generate the '--' (endash) range conjunction symbol, three or more consecutive numbered objects must be in the argument of `\cref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subfigure' environment and counter

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
%% see p. 20 of user guide for '\crefstripprefix' macro:
\crefrangelabelformat{subfigure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
%% Optional: if "Oxford comma" is needed, uncomment the next line:
% \newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and }

\begin{document}

%% generate suitable '\label's for 'figure' and 'subfigure' objects:
\stepcounter{section}
\refstepcounter{figure}    \label{fig:A}   % 1.1
\refstepcounter{subfigure} \label{fig:aaa} % (a)
\refstepcounter{subfigure} \label{fig:bbb} % (b)
\refstepcounter{figure}    \label{fig:B}   % 1.2
\refstepcounter{subfigure} \label{fig:ccc} % (a)
\refstepcounter{subfigure} \label{fig:ddd} % (b)
\refstepcounter{subfigure} \label{fig:eee} % (c)


Cross-references to \cref{fig:aaa,fig:ccc,fig:eee}.

Cross-references to \cref{fig:aaa,fig:ccc,fig:ddd,fig:eee}.
\end{document}
```